# How do I authenticate Google Calendar API v3 without user interaction?

Tags: delphi, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm using Google and external calendar sync (console application). I've tried several ways to connect to my calendar in Delphi. In the latest version of the Google API, you can choose two options:

- API Key (public calendar)
- OAuth2.0 (private calendar)

The calendar is not public. I looked at a couple of examples, but everywhere the need for user interaction. I want to identify myself with no user interaction. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about using it in Delphi but there is a client API library for java, python... I've already used the java one and it's clearly explained how to use it in the documentation.

Google Calendar API 3 Doc page: 
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

However, the service asks you to be authentified to used it (which is your problem if I understand it well, you don't want the user to have to authenticate). So I suggest you to have a look on OAuth2.0. https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

Here are some simple of using google-api-java-client for exemple : https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2

And you should look more precisely at Google OAuth service account possibilities.
Service Account with OAuth2.0. (See here : https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2#serviceaccount).
It will provide a service account for your application, from which you will be able to handle calendars for your app.

And here you will find a sample showing how to do it with Java. (https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Service_Accounts). But maybe this is the public API Key you are talking about... Not sure I remember properly.

I hope this will help you to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. 
I have been thinking of Java.